# Multiprocessing process intermediate output

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

I have a function that loads data and loops through times e.g.

```
def calculate_profit(account):
    account_data = load(account) #very expensive operation
    for day in account_data.days:
        print(account_data.get(day).profit)
```

Because the loading of the data is expensive it makes sense to use joblib/multiprocessing to do something like this:

```
arr = [account1, account2, account3, ...]
joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(calculate_profit)(arr))
```

However, I have another expensive function that I would like to apply on the intermediate results of the `calculate_profit` function. For example, assume that it is an expensive operation to sum up all of the profit and process it/post it to website/etc. Also I need the previous day's profits to calculate the profit change in this function.

```
def expensive_sum(prev_day_profits, *account_profits):
    total_profit_today = sum(account_profits)
    profit_difference = total_profit_today - prev_day_profits

    #some other expensive operation
    #more expensive operations
```

So I would like to

1. Run the multiprocessing processes in parallel (to lessen the load of loading in all of the expensive account data)
2. Once each multiprocessing process hits a predefined point (e.g. finished one iteration of the loop), return those intermediate values to another function (`expensive_sum`) to process - **assume that each individual multiprocessing process cannot continue until** `expensive_sum` **returns**
3. HOWEVER, I want to keep the multiprocessing processes alive so that I don't have to reinitialize them (reducing that overhead)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: does that prevent the individual processes from continuing until the queue returns?

Comment: What amount of data are we talking about for both `load()` and `expensive_sum()`? Because if you're going to be passing big swaths of data you might lose any advantage you'd get by multiprocessing due to the pickling/unpickling ballet Python does when exchanging data between processes.

Comment: individual processes just `put` the values....queue does not return

Comment: @zwer this is just a toy example

Answer (score 1):

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
queue = manager.Queue()
```

> Once each multiprocessing process hits a predefined point
>   do

```
queue.put(item)
```

Meanwhile the other expensive function does

```
queue.get(item)  ==>  blocking call for get
```

The expensive function waits on `get` and goes ahead when it gets a value processes it and again waits on `get`

Comment: thanks - how would you implement the "blocking" call for get?

Comment: @Michael its default blocking...if you want non blocking you would use `get_nowait()`

Comment: Cool thanks! sorry one other question - do you call queue.get from another process? How would you initialize it? For example if i have 10 processes running queue.put(item[[0]), how do I make sure that they don't continue to queue.put(item[1]) before process(item[0], ..., item[1]) finishes?

Comment: @Michael you can use `queue.qsize()` for that...once processing is over queue size will be 0

Comment: @Michael you can create a global `queue` and use it inside processes.....or in `__init__` of the class in which your functions are